# cannot read property 'split' of undefined sqlite ionic-v3 & SQLite

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, storage

I am using ionic-v3 and sqlite plugin. I am trying to create simple database and insert one record inside it then retrieve that record by SELECT Query.

The issue I am having is that the database will not be created and an error will be shown for me 'cannot read property 'split' of undefined sqlite'
and this is will appears in the code when I first write try & catch.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
$ npm install @ionic-native/sqlite
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private db: SQLiteObject;
  public movies: string[] = [];
  public message:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, private sqlite: SQLite, platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.CreateDatabase();
    });
  }

  CreateDatabase()
  {
    try
    {

      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'data.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

          db.executeSql('create table IF NOT EXISTS Movies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(32))', [])
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Table Movies created !');
            this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO `Movies` VALUES (`1`, `James Bond 007`)', [])
            .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
            .catch(e => this.message = e);

        })
        .catch(e => this.message = e);


        })
        .catch(e => this.message = e);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      this.presentToast(err);
    }

  }

  public retrieveFilms() {

    try 
    {
      this.db.executeSql('SELECT name FROM `Movies`', [])
      .then((data) => {
        if(data == null) {
          return;
        }

        if(data.rows) {
          if(data.rows.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
              this.movies.push(data.rows.item(i).name);
            }
          }
        }

      }).catch(e => this.presentToast(JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      this.presentToast(err);
    }

  }

  presentToast(messageText) {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: messageText,
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'bottom'
  });

  toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
    console.log('Dismissed toast');
  });

  toast.present();
}

}
```

What I am doing wrong here ? I've tried everything here in stackoverflow or even from tutorial in youtube or the ionic documentation. but nothing works for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the old **ionic-native/sqlite** version **4.x.x** instead of **5.x.x**. 
I had the same problem when using the newest ionic-native/sqlite with Ionic 3.

Uninstall the old plugin using npm or change it in your **package.json** file.

And You need to change the line:

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
```

to

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it solved part of the problem. Currently the error is (TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined).

Comment: This worked for me. Was using `@ionic-native/sqlite@5.9.0`. Uninstalled it and installed `npm install @ionic-native/sqlite@4.20.0` and the problem went away.

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks. Was struggling with this for too long. @TheSammie thanks for more in depth details, works 100%

Comment: Worked for me changing to legacy import and installing with npm install @ionic-native/sqlite@4.20.0